# Accidentally connected an Atmega328p and an Atmega644p to 12v instead of 5v. Are they screwed? The 328 seems to be bricked, the 644 seems fine.

Tags: atmega, atmel, 12v, 5v

I'm working on a project using the Atmega328p and Atmega644p, so first I built myself a USBasp programmer board for each one and I've successfully programmed a blinking LED, which is awesome!

The not-so-awesome part is that in the process I apparently hooked each chip up to 12v DC on the VCC and AVCC pins. For testing whether my program was written successfully, I built out a small breadboard circuit using a power supply by "Elegoo Electronics" from an assorted kit I bought off amazon. It's supposed to supply 3.3v or 5v depending on where you set a jumper. However, while debugging the fact that my simple LED blinker program/circuit wasn't working, I found out that everywhere on the power supply that says it provides 5v actually provides whatever voltage is coming in the DC in (if I use a 9v adapter, it provides 9v, if I use a 12v adapter it provides 12v).

So now I have a 328 and a 644 that were each connected to 12v DC for a bit. The 644 still works as far as I can tell. I can still flash it, and my program switches its pin on/off every half second just as it's supposed to (as long as I connect it to the 3.3v instead of the so-called 5v). The 328 seems busted though. When I try to flash it with avrdude, I get the following error messages:

```
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
             this check.
```

Is it worth trying to salvage either chip? I bought one extra of each (now I regret not buying a few), so I don't need these two for the actual project. Is there any way I can test the 644 to see if anything was damaged by the 12v? Should I give up on the 328? Is there an obvious reason the 644 is still functioning while the 328 seems destroyed?

Thanks!

Comment: Toast! Nine more characters to fill the minimum.

Comment: As for why the '644 may have survived, read about how a regulator with Zener shunt works -- the '328 may have shunted enough current to pull the supply voltage down to a level that didn't immediately fry the '644.  And don't rely on ever being that lucky again.

Comment: The '644 might not have survived - microcontrollers are complicated, and some internal functions might have been partially damaged. It's hard to test the whole chip once it leaves the factory. But if the *Absolute Maxumum Ratings* were ever exceeded (see datasheet), the warranty is void.

Comment: I hate when that happens.  Ask Atmel for a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12v on an AVR is dicing. quite some times back, I experiemented over voltage on a few chips (PIC, AVR, STM8, and older LM3S). the PICs held quite well, but at 9v Vcc, it is 75/25 survival. AVR was 20/80 survival and LM3S was mostly dead. I would imagine at 12v it is worse for AVR.

Older chips tend to fare better than newer ones.

Comment: Accepted since it's the only answer but the comments on my question were pretty helpful. Thanks people. I wrote "fried" on both chips. Now I know to test the voltage before trying to power these things.